# feedback.stackoverflow.com should also point to meta.stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

"meta" makes sense as url for general discussion about the site and engine, but not as the primary mechanism for feedback, bug reports, or feature requests.

With that in mind, feedback.stackoverflow.com should redirect to meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: In the same spirit, I'd also like to have whydoesntthisthingwork.stackoverflow.com and thispieceofjunkisdrivingmecrazy.stackoverflow.com to redirect here.

Comment: Shouldn't feedback.stackoverflow.com redirect to stackoverflow.uservoice.com ?

Comment: @rowland: they tried that, and there were... problems.  Anyway, the uservoice site is going away.

Comment: @joel IMHO, uservoice worked better for feature request/bug reports. There do seem to be "quite a few" puerile questions, answers and comments on here, with few with the reputation to clean up

Comment: I agree with pesto, what about wtf.stackoverflow.com and fixya.stackoverflow.com and why.stackoverflow.com ??

Answer (score 2):

I Agree. "meta" doesn't tell me that this is for feedback anyway. I had to go here and check it out to figure out what it was about.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this just leads to confusion, why have two URL's going to the same site?

The ~only link to here says "feedback always welcome" (I doubt many people will randomly type "feedback.stackoverflow.com" into their address bar). Plus the existing questions should make it clear what this site is for.

I guess the FAQ or About page should really mention it can be used for feedback or feature-requests a bit more explicitly (than just "discussion")..

Comment: Two links to the same site does not cause confusion, much the same as owning foo.(com|net|org) and pointing them all to the same site.